# Is it possible to apply a view's transform values to it's CAShapeLayer?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, cashapelayer

I want to know that is it possible to apply a view's transform values to its CAShapelayer?. If it is possible, how can I apply transform values, generated from Pinch, Pan, and Rotation gestures?. I don't want to apply the transforms to view itself. Rather than, I want to apply it for the sublayer, a CAShapeLayer class.

Answer (score 0):

`CALayer`, which `CAShapelLayer` inherits from, has it's native transformation property `CATransform3D transform`, which is 3D based. However, you can easily use 2D transforms (as UIView is using) also. Just use the layer's `setAffineTransform:(CGAffineTransform)` method.